# Filling the Multidimensional Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop

I'm newbie to Swift and I got a problem with Swift language.

I should make a function, which creates a 2-dimensional matrix NxN and finds sum of diagonally situated elements. 
I've got some problem with filling an array with random values.

That's my code:

```
import Foundation
func diagonal (N:Int) {
    var array: [[Int]] = [[0],[0]]
    for row in 0...N {
        for col in 0...N {
            var z = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
            array[row][col] = z
        }
    }
    println (array)
}
```

It doesn't work.

So I'm looking forward for your help.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, there'r no errors. The last for-loop (for col in 0...N) executes only twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@matt's answer makes some good points about your current code and highlights the things you need to fix. I wanted to provide an alternative answer to filling the two-dimensional array. Instead of populating the arrays with zeros and then setting each row/column value, you could use `append` to add new values, for example:

```
func diagonal (N:Int) {
    var array: [[Int]] = []

    for row in 0..<N {
        // Append an empty row.
        array.append([Int]())

        for _ in 0..<N {
            // Populate the row.
            array[row].append(Int(arc4random_uniform(100)))
        }
    }

    println(array)
}
```

Using it:

```
diagonal(2)
// [[40, 58], [44, 83]]
```

Comment: I fully support this. This is just what I meant when I said my code was not the only way or the best way. I was just trying to show, using line-by-line contrast, what was glaringly wrong with the original code.

Comment: I know its an old post... now in Swift 5 you have to use:
> diagonal(N: 2)
to call the function or you have to change the header to 
> func diagonal (_ N:Int) {

Answer (score 4):

You are saying:

```
array[row][col] = z
```

There are no "sparse" arrays in Swift. If `row` does not exist — that is, if `array[row]` refers to an index larger than the last existing index of `array` — then you will crash. You cannot simply *assign* to `array[row][col]` and expect magic to happen; you must *ensure* that `array[row][col]` *exists*.

Another problem is that you have confused the range operator `...` with `..<`. In your loops `for row in 0...N` you are going to loop N+1 times, as if the arrays consisted of N+1 elements. That is probably not what you want; you probably intended N to represent the number of elements. So you need to use `..<` instead.

Thus, to sum up everything I've just said and put it into action, your code will run without crashing if you replace the relevant three lines like this:

```
var array: [[Int]] = Array(count:N, repeatedValue:Array(count:N, repeatedValue:0))
for row in 0..<N {
    for col in 0..<N {
```

That is not the *only* way or even the *best* way to do what you are trying to do, but at least it makes sense, which is more than your code can claim!

Comment: Yeah, I've had read about what you've written here. I was looking for the way without using "repeatedValue". And thank's about the range operator :) I'll try both ways, yours and @ABakerSmith's. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
public func  getLine() -> String {

    var buf = String()
    var c = getchar()

    while c != EOF && c != 10 {
        buf.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(c))!))
        c = getchar()
    }
    return buf
}


print("Enter value of Rows and Coloums :")

let rows = Int(getLine())
let coloums = Int(getLine())

print("Enter values in Array(rows * coloums):")

var array = [[Int]]()

for i in 0 ..< (rows ?? 0){

    var rowArray = [Int]()

    for j in 0 ..< (coloums ?? 0) {

        rowArray.append(Int(getLine())!)
    }

    array.append(rowArray)
}

print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

The two answers above cover all of the highlights and rectify the issue that the OP encountered. However, they are a bit dated and lack flexibility.

The following provides a custom initializer on `[Int]` to support populating a 2D array with random values.

```
extension Array where Element == [Int] {
    init(row: Int, col: Int, min: Int, max: Int) {
        precondition(min <= max)
        self.init()
        for index in 0..<row { 
            append([Int]())
            for _ in 0..<col {
                self[index].append(Int.random(in: min...max))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A quick overview of what is going on:

1. `Precondition` ensures that the `min` value does not exceed `max`, otherwise your random function will crash
2. An empty `[Int]` is created
3. It iterates for the row count, creating an empty `[Int]` that is added to itself
4. Then it iterates again down each column, appending a random `Int` within your defined range

You can call it with this:

```
let matrix = [[Int]](row: 10, col: 10, min: 0, max: 99)
```

As an aside, if you want an equal count of row & col, you can make another init that accepts a single size, and then calls into this one (or just replace row/col with size).