# How do I properly create a multidimensional array in swift?

Tags: swift, for-loop, multidimensional-array, append

I have created a multidimensional array, but as soon as I try to add values to it at specific indexes it crashes with an `index out of range` message. I think it has to do with the way I initialise the array - that I have to be more specific about what it can store etc. At this thread: [Filling the Multidimensional Array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288722/filling-the-multidimensional-array-in-swift) it was suggested that I should initialise the array like this (obviously modified for my purposes):

`var array: [[Int]] = Array(count:N, repeatedValue:Array(count:N, repeatedValue:0))`

But I didn't get it to work, nor understood it properly. Below is the code I have. It crashes on the last code line.

```
    var multiArray = [[Tile]]()

    var gb = gameBoard.frame.width/4

    for xItem in 0...3 { //DRAW TILE ON X AXIS

        for yItem in 0...3 { //DRAW TILE ON Y AXIS
            //CREATES A VARIABLE FOR TILE WITH PROPERTIES
            tileView = Tile(frame: CGRect(x: (CGFloat(xItem) * gb), y: (CGFloat(yItem) * gb), width: gb, height: gb))

            gameBoard.addSubview(tileView) //DRAWS TILE ONTO PARENT VIEW
            multiArray[xItem][yItem] = tileView   //CRASHES HERE WHEN TRYING TO ADD TO INDEX
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really creating an array of arrays.  You can't access indices that aren't created yet, so instead just create one column at a time and append items to it and then append each column array to the the `multiArray`:

```
var multiArray = [[Tile]]()

var gb = gameBoard.frame.width/4

for xItem in 0...3 { //DRAW TILE ON X AXIS
    var col = [Tile]()

    for yItem in 0...3 { //DRAW TILE ON Y AXIS
        //CREATES A VARIABLE FOR TILE WITH PROPERTIES
        tileView = Tile(frame: CGRect(x: (CGFloat(xItem) * gb), y: (CGFloat(yItem) * gb), width: gb, height: gb))

        gameBoard.addSubview(tileView) //DRAWS TILE ONTO PARENT VIEW
        col.append(tileView)
    }

    multiArray.append(col)
}
```

---

The method you mentioned for initializing a multiArray works best if your array is filled with value types (such as `Int` or `Double`) and you have a reasonable default value (such as `0`).  It doesn't work as well if your array will be holding class instances.  You *could* make your array `[[Tile?]]` and initialize it with `nil` values, but then you'd have to deal with unwrapping the optionals later.  The `append` method is best for your case.

Comment: If `Tile` is a struct it would work. Just loop through and update each frame.

Comment: Ah, I see, so rather than specifying indexes I have to actually create a separate array and append it to the multi array. It works perfect! Thank you @vacawama for your assistance and for taking the time helping me out. Much appreciated! :)