# How to fill 2dimensional array with custom objects? swift

Tags: arrays, swift, oop, grid

I trying to make project where I have  grid board and characters like Fish and Orca. I created Animal parent class and two child class that inherit animal. And I want to fill board (n * m)  with 5% Orca and 35% Fish.  How can I fill the grid with orca and fish? here I tried to fill the board with numbers.

```
class Animal {


}
class Fish: Animal{
}
class Orca:Animal{
}
class Board{
private var content: [[Int?]]
private static func setupForNewGame(width: Int,height: Int)->[[Int]]{

    var matrix:[[Int]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: width), count: height)
    let cellCount = width * height

    var penguinCount = Double(round(Double(cellCount) * 50.0 / 100.0))
    var grampusCount = Double(round(Double(cellCount) * 5.0 / 100.0))

    var arr:[Int] = Array(repeating: 0, count: cellCount)
    for i in 0...cellCount - 1{
        if (penguinCount > 0){
            arr[i] = 1
            penguinCount = penguinCount - 1
        }else if (grampusCount > 0){
            arr[i] = 2
            grampusCount = grampusCount - 1
        }else{
            arr[i] = 0
        }
    }
    let shuffledArr = arr.shuffled()
    var counter = 0
    for i in 0...width - 1{
        for j in 0...height - 1{
           matrix[i][j] = shuffledArr[counter]
            counter = counter + 1
        }

    }

    return matrix

}
}
```

Comment: To fill 2dimensional array with custom objects need to
[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288722/filling-the-multidimensional-array-in-swift)

Comment: Note: `0...width - 1` is better written as `0 ..< width` in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `matrix` array of type `[[Animal?]]` and use `nil` instead of `0`

```
class Board {
    private var content: [[Animal?]] = []
    private static func setupForNewGame(width: Int,height: Int)->[[Animal?]] {

        var matrix:[[Animal?]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: nil, count: width), count: height)
        let cellCount = Double(width * height)

        let fishCount = Int(cellCount * 35.0 / 100.0)
        let orcaCount = Int(cellCount * 5.0 / 100.0)

        var arr:[Animal?] = Array(1...fishCount).map { _ in Fish() } + Array(1...orcaCount).map { _ in Orca() } + Array(repeating: nil, count: Int(cellCount)-fishCount-orcaCount)
        arr = arr.shuffled()

        var counter = 0
        for i in 0...width - 1{
            for j in 0...height - 1{
                matrix[i][j] = arr[counter]
                counter = counter + 1
            }
        }
        return matrix
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr` won’t have enough items to fill the `matrix` as it is only 40% as large.

Comment: @vacawama Yes. Other elements will be nil

Comment: But won’t you run out of elements as you are filling the matrix resulting in an index out of range error?

Comment: Now your creatures are are jammed at the start of your matrix. How about putting enough nils into `arr` and shuffling those as well?

Comment: @vacawama Yes. I thought thats what OP wants

Comment: OP’s `arr` has `width * height` elements before shuffling, so enough to fill `matrix` with animals evenly distributed.